# Calling from an Sybase Database ODBC

Tags: php, python, mysql, odbc, sybase

I am writing a scheduling program for my company and I wanted to pull information from our Management Information System to supplement the schedule. The MIS has information on all of the jobs we need to run including due dates, piececounts, operations, estimated run times and other valuable information for a scheduler. I talked to support for the software and they basically stonewalled me. They kept avoiding my questions.

When I forced the issue by having the CEO call them, they gave up the database was a Sybase database and that it was ODBC compliant. Then they me a 500 page document of the data mappings of the database, but no explanation. Looking through it, i can tell a lot of it is just general settings for the software, and i believe i found the tables that store the job information. But i have no idea what the fields in the table are.

I connected to the ODBC connection successful in a python interpreter shell. I did a select * from table statement and i got a crapton of information back. But i dont know what i selected. Is there any way to see what fields im collecting information from?

So Basically I am asking if there is a way to know what information i drew from a table without knowing the field names.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were the CEO, my first thought would be to [buy scheduling software](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=scheduling+and+optimization+software#pq=scheduling+and+optimization+software&hl=en&cp=17&gs_id=3w&xhr=t&q=manufacturing+scheduling+software&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=manufacturing+sch&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2f0b188327e19041&biw=1152&bih=595) before I'd ask an individual or team in my company to write such a thing.  It's a difficult but important problem.  Why would you want to develop, debug, and maintain such a thing?  It's been solved.  I'd rather just use an existing solution.  Just saying.

> I am asking if there is a way to know what information i drew from a
>   table without knowing the field names.

The field names and types are the easy part.  You can ask Sybase to [DESCRIBE TABLE](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbreference_en11/describe-statement.html).  It'll give you all the column names and types.

But it won't have any meta-data that gives you *business context* for what they mean.  You'll have to go back to that MIS group, domain experts, or know the process well yourself to figure that out.

Comment: The MIS is written by a third party company. They were willing to do the scheduling code for us for a very hefty price. The problem is our industry is very fast paced and has a lot of variables. This MIS is the only one we know of to manage and estimate for the number of different types of operations and the number of jobs we run. For scheduling we could be running 110 jobs at any one point on about 80 different machines. So the scheduling program needs to know what operations each job has to go through, and what machines do those operations, which is to complex for a cookie cutter scheduler

Comment: I am just laying the groundwork for the scheduling program. Once I get a handle on what needs to be done, I will be hiring some people to help write and maintain it.

Comment: Also thank you for the describe table. I am quite familiar with MySQL and wasnt sure if the commands carried over to Sybase or ODBC

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with how manufacturing works - I used to be a mechanical engineer at a jet engine manufacturer.  (You can bet that my former employer is not writing their own scheduler.)  I'd wonder about "hefty".  Without knowing the details, I'm sure you and your CEO have convinced yourselves that you can do it cheaper by comparing your estimate with their price, but you're leaving out a lot of your cost when you do that.  Your estimate is optimistic; you leave out the cost and time they've spent debugging with real clients; etc.

Comment: the biggest kicker with their system is the licensing cost and its rigidity. Most of the people who use this companies software dont like it, however it is the only option anyone knows about. That in mind, upper management wasnt about to have more software developed by them. And any solution we bought from them we would pay for every year, and its not cheap. Also they would also be doing the scheduler from scratch, so its a choice between hiring a company whose software we have had problems with before, and customizing a solution ourselves using unused programmers we have on staff.

Comment: I have never heard of a company that was delighted with their ERP provider.  I agree that you're right to seek another solution if they don't have a scheduler on the shelf.  You'd be doing yourself a service by looking into the best off the shelf solution out there.  You aren't the first to deal with this problem.  I'll bet there are more complex manufacturing operations out there, and they need scheduling, too.  The one I worked for was part of a Dow Jones company; they made jet engines.  (I'll give you two guesses as to which company it was.)

Comment: This company isn't nearly as big. We have looked at other scheduling software and have had some quoted to fit our situation. However the prices we are getting back are an order of magnitude or two out of our price range. The schedule is currently a excel document that entire department manages as jobs come in. Shoe network system that is inefficient works well enough not to invest a quarter million dollars in software. Attempting to replace the shoe network with in house software using programmers who are intimately familiar with the system already seemed like a more cost effective solution.

Comment: Then I'd recommend looking at algorithms like simulated annealing or genetic algorithms to help you.  Good luck.